# mvc url working on local but not on server

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am working in asp.net MVC....
Not sure if this is a bug, or a misconfiguration on my part, but the `&format=` doesn't work on the IIS7 staging server but it works fine on local VS Web server(2008)
i.e. `http://localhost:12345/<p1>/<p2>/&format=xml` works, but 
`www.example.com/<p1>/<p2>/&format=xml` doesn't.

please let me know what can be the problem & how can i resolve that
thanks in advance
gbhatnagar

Answer (score 0):

I happened across an article which shows how to debug routes - http://stephenwalther.com/blog/archive/2008/08/03/asp-net-mvc-tip-29-build-a-controller-to-debug-your-custom-routes.aspx  Now I am not sure what the issue might be, but this might help to determine what isn't the issue.  Hope this helps.

Wade